# Visual Studio Cordova FileTransfer Download

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, file-transfer, visual-studio-cordova

I have created a simple Apache Cordova App, 
I have added the File Transfer plugin
Here is my code:

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();

ft.download('http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300.jpg',
    'ms-appdata:///fillmurray.js',
    function () {
        console.log('success');
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log('failed');
    }
);
```

But i keep getting this error:

> Exception calling native with command :: FileTransfer :: download ::exception=WinRTError: The parameter is incorrect.

Any ideas?